# The torsion on the spherical curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I am currently studying for an exam in differential geometry. There's a problem which I am not able to solve and do not even know where to start.

There is the curve β on the spherical surface. which radius is *a*.

If curve $\alpha$ is defined as $$\alpha(t)=\int \beta(t)\times\beta '(t)dt$$
show that torsion $\tau$ is $\frac{1}{a^2}$

---

By advice, to find binormal, I started to find $$\alpha'(t)\times\alpha''(t)$$
$$\alpha'(t)=\beta(t)\times\beta'(t)$$
$$\alpha''(t)=\beta(t)\times\beta''(t)$$
so $$\alpha'(t)\times\alpha''(t)=((\beta(t)\times\beta'(t))\cdot\beta''(t))\beta(t)$$
but how can I found  $$\left|\alpha'(t)\times\alpha''(t)\right|$$?

And by knowing that binormal is $\pm\beta$  , how can I found a torsion?
Maybe $\beta'(t)$ is tangent.
And maybe $$\beta(t)\cdot\beta(t)=a^2$$
by derivative it, $$\beta'(t)\cdot\beta(t)=0$$
This is the whole thing that I can do.
With that idea... still I can't find the way to solve...

Comment: **HINT**: Show that the binormal is $\pm\beta$.

Comment: sorry.... why binormal is $\pm \beta$?

Comment: I'm telling you to figure that out.

Comment: okay, I'll try it out more.

Comment: More explicit hint: What direction is orthogonal to $\alpha’$ and $\alpha”$?

Comment: $\alpha'$ $\alpha''$ is orthogonal in binormal. and I'm trying to get $\alpha''$ to get binormal of $a(t)$.

$$\alpha''(t)=(\frac{d}{dt}\beta\times\frac{d}{dt}\beta)+(\beta\times\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\beta)=(\beta\times\beta'')$$
then $$\alpha'(t)\times\alpha''(t)=(\beta(t)\times\beta'(t))\times(\beta(t)\times\beta''(t))=((\beta(t)\times\beta'(t))\cdot\beta''(t))\beta(t)$$
Is $$(\beta(t)\times\beta'(t))\cdot\beta''(t))=1?$$
and I still don't know why torsion be like that.

Comment: We don't even have an arclength parametrization. But you've established my hint. So what is $dB/ds$?

Comment: Isn't it tangent?

Comment: Frenet tells you that $dB/ds = -\tau N$. But you know $dB/dt = \beta'$. So how do you find $dB/ds$? You are correct that $\beta\cdot\beta' = 0$, which tells you that $\|\alpha'\| = \|\beta\times\beta'\| = a\|\beta'\|$ (why?).

Comment: I really thanks for your help. I found that torsion is
$(\beta(t)\times\beta'(t))\cdot\beta''(t) \over \left| \beta(t) \right|$
and 
$\left| \beta(t) \right|$ is *a*

so $(\beta(t)\times\beta'(t))\cdot\beta''(t)$
have to be $ 1 \over a $

why?

Comment: Actually, I lied. Since $\|\beta\|=a$, we have $B = \pm\beta/a$. I'm not suggesting using that formula for torsion; I'm suggesting thinking it through from first principles. However, I don't believe that formula is correct. You need $\tau = \frac{\alpha'\cdot(\alpha''\times\alpha''')}{\|\alpha'\times\alpha''\|^2}$. So I definitely do not follow. Also, I just realized that the problem left out an important hypothesis: You need to know that $\beta,\beta',\beta''$ are linearly independent at each $t$.